# iPhone: remove section in TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm working with table view and sections...In some case I need do remove one section, in another set it back. I can do that in 2 ways:
1)

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (somecase) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

and  than

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:nil];
    [tableViewCell autorelease];

    tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    if (sectionNumber == 3 {
        switch (indexPath.section) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
        }
    } else if (sectionNumber == 2) {
        switch (indexPath.section) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
        }
        return tableViewCell;
    }
}
```

And a second way is to implement

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:NO];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

But it's not working...I put this methods to ViewDidLoad, is that ok ? Or I should put in somewhere else ? Or what is the problem ?

And what is the best practice for removing section ? first one or second ? thanks....

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not working"? Your cellForRowAtIndexPath: code should also take "somecase" into account. You always need the first two methods, and use the code snipped with the updates/delete to remove one section when it is already available.

Comment: Where to put updates/delete methods ?

Comment: In code that executes at the time when you want to remove the data?!

Comment: I put that in ViewDidLoad just to try to remove section, but section still exist...Why ?

Comment: Check your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: implementation, and maybe log if your condition is really met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- set condition that will satisfy "somecase " then reload tableview

[tableview reloadData];